# asp.net button reloads page instead of executing code

Tags: asp.net, button

I am writing an asp.net website and im trying to use the asp.net button. Though the code behind is correct and i used the update panel, every time i click on the button the code behind does not execute and instead of that the page reloads. Can you please help me?

Here is the part of the code i use the button:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-offset-4 padding-left-0 padding-top-20">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" >

            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button  class="btn btn-primary" ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Log in" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLogin" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the unwanted behavior happen if you remove the UpdateMode="Conditional" property and the Triggers inner tag of the UpdatePanel?

Comment: Yeap, still not working. im using the metronic theme, if this matters..

Comment: Set a break point (debugger) in the server click event of the button and check whether it is executed.

The bootstrap theme should not be a problem.

Comment: I set two break points, one on the page load event and one on the server click event. both times (when first time loading the page and when the button is clicked) the debugger stops at the page load break point. So server code is never executed but i cant figure out why

Comment: Try to create the Button Click handler by double clicking on the button in the Visual Studio Designer. If this does not help and you still experience the problem, create a new aspx page with a button and a click handler and test again.

Comment: I did, still didnt work. I did it again using different master page and this time it did work, so i guess the problem is somewhere in my master page. Thanks for the help

Comment: This is a good start :) Compare both pages and start to remove content from the problematic one until you locate the issue. After that you can share your findings... Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it, somewhere in the master page there was an "action" field in the form, i removed it and its all okay now. Thanks Rumen for the help